# Looking for book written by imprisoned Chinese author, first page setting is on a train

Tags: identification-request

I am looking for the book title of a recently translated book by a Chinese author, who wrote the notes for the book while she was imprisoned in China.

The contents seemed to be a light novel, and the first scene in the book was of several characters having a conversation in a train in China.

I tried looking for recent titles from China, but did not find the book I was looking for.